# Is it possible to get a list of all Teams in a tenant?

Tags: office365, powerbi, microsoft-teams

I know this hasn't been an option for a long time, but is there any way yet to get a list of the active Teams on our Tenant?  Is there possibly a solution in PowerBi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on the APIs to get all the teams belong to a particular tenant; which should be ready by the end of September 2018. Once it is ready, [joinedTeams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) API will return all the teams in a tenant for the tenant admin users.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it!!

Comment: Let me start by saying I have no experience (yet) with Teams.
Will we be able to call this api from any code or is this only available to Graph?

I have an inhouse webapp that lets our users search for project folders based on (partial) project information. These used to only be on our networkstorage but they have started using Teams. I've now been asked to see if it's possible to add Teams to the search. I don't need to search in the teams, I only need the names of all of our companies teams (I assume that's one tenant) as the projectnumber is part of the Teamname.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we don't have directly way to get the list of the active Teams on our Tenant, but I can provide an workaround for you.

First, use the [graph user api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list) to get the user list of current Tenant. And then iterate over the result list and call [JoinedTeams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) for every user. Finally, combine the all teams into one list.

Some pseudo-code:

```
var userList= GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
List<Object> teamList=new List<Object>();
foreach(user in userList)
{
   var teamsForUser= GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams
   teamList.AddRange(teamsForUser);
}
```

Add a [simple way](https://sharepoint-specialist.nu/get-all-teams-in-a-tenant-using-microsoft-graph-255f374d5c3a):

```
  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq ‘Team’)”
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a PowerShell script a while ago and published it in the TechNet Script Gallery, to retrieve a list of all Microsoft Teams within your organization.

It's published at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-a-list-of-all-Teams-68a45e0a

For more information on how to use it, you may refer to my blog post at https://www.srdn.io/2018/08/get-all-microsoft-teams-within-your-organization/

[image]

Comment: Thanks John.   Looking forward to trying this.